# Changing font-feature-settings with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, font-feature-settings

I'm trying to activate different stylistic sets, in this example with a button.

My code:

```
<p id="demo">B</p>

<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').style.fontFeatureSettings ='ss01'">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: Why not simply by changing  class values ?

Comment: `fontFeatureSettings` is a CSS property, not a HTMLElement property

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry! Missed the .style, edited the post. Problem remains though.

Comment: @MisterJojo thank you, could you point me to an example of how this is done?

Comment: when you say "problem remains" ... what IS the problem? what do you expect to see? what do you see instead?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, the value `ss01` needs to be `"ss01"` ... in `onclick=` that's going to get a little messy, though doable like so:

```
<button type="button"
    onclick="document.getElementById('demo').style.fontFeatureSettings
        ='@quot;ss01@quot;'">
    Click Me!
</button>
```

(Note: I made it multiline so it's easy to read here)

I would use `addEventListener` instead for cleaner looking code

```js
document.getElementById("theButton").addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('demo').style.fontFeatureSettings ='"ss01"';
});
```

```html
<p id="demo">B</p>

<button type="button" id="theButton">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

1)Have you import the font in your head?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nome+del+Font">
```

2)if you want to change only the style you need to write:

```
document.getElementById('demo').style.fontFamily = "'Roboto', sans-serif";
```

3. You can also use the line below to activate a specific set of styles:

   document.getElementById('demo').style.fontFeatureSettings = "'ss01'";

However, please note that not all browsers support all sets of styles, and you should check in the font documentation if the specific set of styles (such as SS01) is included.

Comment: As per the third point, it won't work in HTML document (using onclick) . It is better to use an event listener as suggested in other responses

Answer (score 0):

First of All
1 - `font-feature-settings` work's **ONLY** on **OpenType fonts**

> Why not simply by changing class values ?

> could you point me to an example of how this is done?

```js
const
  myButton = document.querySelector('#my-button')
, p_Dema   = document.querySelector('p#demo')
  ;
myButton.addEventListener('click', () =>
  {
  p_Dema.classList.toggle('fontFeature_Zero');
  });
```

```css
p  {
    font-family : 'Linux Libertine Display O'; /* OpenType font */ 
    font-size   : 2em;
  font-feature-settings: normal;
  }
 
.fontFeature_Zero {
  font-feature-settings: "zero";
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"  > 0 - O</p>

<button type="button" id="my-button">Click Me!</button>
```